# does this sound natural?

Tags: grammar

During an online session:

student:

"before this time, the internet connection was kind of unstable."

"The internet connection was unstable several sessions before."

"The internet connection was unstable The other times."

Are they all correct? which one sounds more natural?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are going to kind of depend on context. For the first one, it would make sense if there was a time period referenced just before you wrote this sentence. If you meant a single event, you might change it to:  " Previously, the internet connection had been unstable." or " Prior to that, the internet connection had been unstable."

If you're talking in the present, you might go with "Until now, the internet connection was kind of unstable." or "Before , the internet connection was unstable." 
Looking at your sentence again, just changing "this time" into "now" could be enough to make it look right.

---

For your second sentence, I'd make some small changes - "The internet connection has been unstable in other sessions." (The has been makes the "before" unnecessary.) You could also use "for several sessions". But I would definitely put a preposition between "unstable" and "several". As it is now, I read it it as "several sessions ago" (before now), which I don't think is your intended meaning.

---

For your third sentence - This looks fine, and would also work as "The other times, the internet connection was unstable." You could also go with "The internet connection was unstable previously." or "in previous sessions".

I think your third sentence is the most natural for casual conversation, and most accurately conveys what I think you're trying to convey.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot JKreft

Comment: @AlexHe Don't forget to mark the answer as a solution if it fully answers your question.

Comment: Omg I just find out this function...